# Curly bracket not missing but is reported to be

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

So I was writing a class file for my player like this:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        public Transform transform;
        public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    }
}
```

And apparently this is what Unity and Visual Studio responded with:

```
Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(7,6): error CS1513: } expected
Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(11,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

How can I fix this code? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You have attempted to define two public fields within the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have attempted to define two public fields within the constructor. I believe what you need is following

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {

    }

    public Transform transform;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are off-topic such as those caused by a typographical error

Comment: @Ruzihm I agree and I was actually tempted to leave the comment instead of answer, but showing the right code in comment might have made it difficult to read.

Comment: @FlipperCanoe163 Glad it worked, kindly mark it as answer/helpful if it was useful in resolving your issue